# Criar função de timezone para PHP e MySql UTC

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou migrando para uma hospedagem Cloud na qual o MySql é com timezone UTC, não consegui executar os comandos pra trocar para o GMT -3 e o suporte não me da outra opção.

Hoje meus pedidos são salvos no Banco de Dados com a data/hora do próprio banco, então pensei em fazer uma função ou algum ajuste no próprio PHP, mas ainda sem sucesso.

**Ultima tentativa**

`<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
?>`

Comment: Tentou executar `SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";` no mysql logo após conectar ao banco?

Comment: Tentei e também não foi, tive que mudar a hospedagem para uma no BR, mas obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Na verdade minha sugestão foi confusa, precisaria mudar para -3 no código do meu comentário anterior

Comment: Sim, eu fiz com -03:00 mas também não foi, tentei inclusive importar o banco com esta função.